# Why pycharm passes breakpoint

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev

My problem is when I put a breakpoint to the code it pass the breakpoint. I debugged the code (also added `PYCHARM_DEBUG=TRUE`) to envinronmental variables)  and below is the error:

> pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does
>   not exist: c:\users\toshıba\pycharmprojects\untitled10\fzxczxc.py
>   (will have no effect)
>
> Added
>   breakpoint:c:\users\toshıba\pycharmprojects\untitled10\fzxczxc.py -
>   line:2 - func_name:b'None'

Comment: You have a unicode character in your path, that's always a candidate for causing filename troubles.